# Scrapy login to website, login data is displayed in the redirected url

Tags: python, python-3.x, xpath, web-scraping, scrapy

**Introduction**

For some tasks, i need to login to get some special information about some products.
I already achieved to login at some pages, but on https://www.duif.nl/ i can not accomplish it. I recognized in my console, that the link i get referred to after the login process does contain my login data, which is different to the site i logged in before.

What is the reason for it?
Does this cause my problem?

I didnt find any example of my problem

My code below is just a very basic and default "login" spider

**My Code**

```py
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import scrapy
from scrapy.http import FormRequest
from scrapy.utils.response import open_in_browser
from ..items import ScrapyloginItem

class DuifLogin(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "duiflogin"
    start_urls = ['https://www.duif.nl/login']

    def parse(self, response):
        yield FormRequest.from_response(response,formdata={
            'username' : '*****',
            'password' : '*****',
        },callback=self.after_logging)

    def after_logging(self, response):
        open_in_browser(response)
        
        card = response.xpath('//div[@class="row myaccountrow"]')

        if card:
            print('success')

        else:
            print(':(')
```

**My Console**

[image: Console]

**Open in browser**

[image: browser]

this is what i see, but when i go to "login" and press enter, nothing happens, thats very strange too

Comment: When open_in_browser method is called, what do you see ? The referral looks to me like an authentication process to make sure that your username and password are correct. Do you get any successful output after logging ? As I can't see the page you speak of its hard to know whether the XPATH selectors for the card variable are what they should be, you may be logging in successfully but the XPATH selector is not correct for example. It might be worth printing response.body in the after_logging function, see if the FormRequest is actually sending the correct information to the login page.

Comment: Hey @AaronS, i uploaded a screenshot of the "browser output" im stuck on this problem since yesterday, its such a pain for me :> the first page i tried to login, it was not that hard, maybe 2 hours and i got it, but this shop makes my day really hard..

Comment: Not really sure what to make of that image, there's no CSS, looks like a old lynx browser output from the 1990's... Check that the FormRequest is sending the correct information by seeing what response.body comes outwith. Looks like you might have to send some login cookies with the FormRequest given the image you've updated. The alternative to FormRequest would be use something like splash/selenium if you're really struggling with getting FormRequest to work. FormRequest is just boilerplate which recognises form HTML, not every website is standard.

Comment: i guess pause this project a bit, do you mind, if i edit my question above and can help me out a bit? I can log in, but it doesnt scrape anything :/

Comment: there is more than one form in the page, you need to make sure that you post matches all "hidden" fields when submitting the "log in"

Comment: how do i find the "hidden" fields? When i check the form data in my browser, there are only 2 fields, like username and password :/